# Expanding lambda functions in python g(f)[0](4,2)

Tags: python, lambda

I'm new to python and higher-order functions and I'm having a lot of trouble simplifying nested lambda functions:

```
f = lambda f, g: (f, (g))
g = lambda g: g(g, g)
print(g(f)[0](4, 2))
```

I've tried expanding `g(f)` giving:

`f(f, f)[0](4, 2)`

but I get stuck after that.

The expected answer is `(4, 2)` - can someone explain why?

Comment: Probably changing *lambda* argument names would make things a bit clearer: `f = lambda x, y: (x, y)`, `g = lambda x: x(x, x)`.

Comment: Is there a reason why `(g)` has these parentheses? Either it's a tuple, then it should be `(g,)` or it's just `g`, then the parentheses can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
g(f)[0](4,2) = f(f,f)[0](4,2) = (f,(f))[0](4,2) = f(4,2) = (4,2)
```